# Many to many relationship users to times logged in/out - how to make scalable calculation of total avail time?

Tags: excel, if-statement, time

I've been trying to do the following:

I have a list of data - can be anything from 10k-200k entries.

The schema is along the lines of:

```
Connection Status | Timestamp | Username
```

Sample data has been included below.

We could have multiple entries per username, and a user can log in or out as many times in a day as required (reachable, unreachable).

The data will always be for a particular day (`0000 to 2359` each day)

I'm trying to figure out the percentage of logged in time against total session time.

I can easily find the total session time by creating a pivot, and working out the max-min to get the total session time.

What I'm struggling with is creating a formula to calculate the actual logged in time.

So for example:

```
USERNAME | STATUS   | TIME STAMP
User1    | logs in  | 08:00
User1    | logs out | 08:30
User1    | logs in  | 10:00
User1    | logs out | 12:00
User1    | logs in  | 15:00
User1    | logs out | 16:00
```

Total time here would be 8 hours.
Actual in use time would be:

```
0830-0800 = 0.5 hours
+
1200-1000 = 2 hours
+
1600-1500 = 1 hour
= 3.5 hours total.
```

This would mean a calculation that will check the first user it starts with (User1), checks if it's User1 we're dealing with (if not, will reset total time to 0 for the next user or something along those lines).

This then needs to check if the status associated with the time is "Reachable" or "Unreachable".

We can have multiple reachable/unreachable such that we don't always have reachable, unreachable. (We could have multiple instances that are reported as reachable before the next unreachable) but in this case, we're only interested in the first instance of the new status and ignore the rest until a new status is found.

For example:

```
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:25   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:25   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:59   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 08:00   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 09:57   |user2
```

I'm only interested in the first instance, as it continues to be reachable until 0957.

Is there a way to do this, or am I going about this in completely the wrong fashion? I could also perhaps write an application, or use Access to handle some of this (??)

Sorry if this question is unclear, it's the best that I can articulate it. If you need clarification, I'll try my best.

Thanks all,

Edit: AP Forward Ed, I'll include a sample of some data... I hope this is how I do it.

```
Status      |Time               |User Name
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:57   |user1
Unreachable |01/06/2016 07:16   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 07:16   |user1
Unreachable |01/06/2016 09:14   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 09:25   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 09:25   |user1
Unreachable |01/06/2016 10:50   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:33   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:33   |user1
Unreachable |01/06/2016 13:13   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 14:15   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 14:15   |user1
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:25   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:25   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 06:59   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 08:00   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 09:57   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 10:00   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 10:00   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 10:27   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 10:54   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 10:54   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 11:24   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 11:24   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 11:24   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 11:33   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 11:33   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 11:33   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 11:59   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:05   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:05   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:11   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:15   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:15   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:15   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:15   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:16   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:17   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:17   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:18   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:20   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:20   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:21   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:21   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:21   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:21   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:21   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:22   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:22   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:22   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:22   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:23   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:30   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:30   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:36   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:36   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:36   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:36   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:37   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:37   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:37   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:37   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 12:41   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:58   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:58   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 13:00   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 13:02   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 13:16   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 13:36   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 13:36   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 13:36   |user2
Unreachable |01/06/2016 13:48   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 14:04   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 14:04   |user2
Reachable   |01/06/2016 07:00   |user3
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:44   |user3
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:44   |user3
Reachable   |01/06/2016 12:52   |user3
Unreachable |01/06/2016 14:19   |user3
Reachable   |01/06/2016 14:19   |user3
```

We call it Reachable/Unreachable but yeah - same thing!

This is a small sample, but yes we have 2,3, maybe 4k users to trawl through sometimes.

Comment: Edit the example table I made out of your words to reflect some of the actual situation you will be dealing with such as double log ins and multiple user.  People responding to your queue love to have data they can copy and paste into their own spreadsheets to lay with.

Comment: Done. Ah wait, I didn't see THAT edited table! 1 sec... ok done :)

Comment: When you have double reachables, they are always the same time.  was that just you copying to generate that or will they actually be the same time?

Comment: No, sadly this isn't the case - in this sample yes, but for example I have a user that shows: 
>Reachable 01/06/2016 06:54, 
>Reachable 01/06/2016 06:55, 
>Unreachable 01/06/2016 11:21, 
>Unreachable 01/06/2016 11:36, 

Oh wow, ok it doesn't display it very well but yeah...

Comment: Oh and I just noticed the last status might not always be a log out. Annoying, but I can still take session time as max of time in the day - min of time in the day.

Comment: I think you need to step back a moment and think about how to deal with the status (reach/unreach) times and how to deal with things.  when you have edit your question and rephrase things to more clearly explain what you want, and how you want to handle special cases such us multiple logins as you originally stated.   Keep the language consistent to avoid ambiguity and confusion.  Lots of people willing to help when questions are clear.  and they will love your sample data!  +2 for that!

Comment: Ok sure, let me have a think about how I'd want to handle these situations - you're right in that I can't ask for help unless I know! I'll come back here shortly...
Thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a lot of to-ing and fro-ing, I've managed to come up with a solution.

By changing the formatting of the SS on the times from ddmmyy hhmm to hhmmss.

I added a new column to the table called difference. I set the very first value to 0. All the other values would be next timestamp - current. Also used a max(0,xx) so that any negative values, which would signify a change of username, would be dealt with accordingly.

It's by no means a perfect solution, as I know there are some scenarios where this falls short - but for this type of task, ROM is fine.

Following this a pivot, or similar table to produce sum by username and connection status allows the desired values to be derived.

I thank you, Forward Ed for your help with this.

Cheers all!

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong.  Session time will be the earliest log in time to the latest log out time.   Every day starts with a log in and will end with a log out.  There will be an equal number of log ins and log outs to a day.

That being said, to find the logged on time for each user you need to do the following.

1)  Generate a list of unique user names
2)  Place the following formula in the adjacent column to determine time logged in.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($G$12:$G$17="username")*(H12:H17="out")*I12:I17)-SUMPRODUCT(($G$12:$G$17="username")*(H12:H17="in")*I12:I17)
```

Where:

G12:G17 is your list of non-unique user names
H12:H17 is your status in/out
I12:I17 is your time stamp in excel time format

To generate a list of unique names, there are other question on SO or google that will give you the process for generating a unique list in excel.

When you have your unique list, edit user name, and point it to the cell of the first name in your unique list and copy down as needed.

Comment: Hi Forward Ed - You're correct in first point - total time is last logout time. Sadly, there are times when a user could login/out twice in a row - usually due to change in network used (e.g. mobile data to wifi or similar) - but this is a good place to start, going to give this a go and see what I can make of it... thank you

Comment: you will need to determine what you plan to do if you have multiple log ins or log outs that are unmatched.  If you are going through the list with say something like VBA and its keeping track of Log in log out status as it runs the list, you could have VBA insert a logout time equal to a sequential log in time.  opposite would be good for sequential log out times by same user.

Comment: I could try and learn some VBA, unsure of my approach, currently - biggest issue I see with this is that each user will have widely varying numbers of login/logout events, so hard coding the cell numbers won't work in this instance.

Comment: you dont need to hardcode the cell references in VBA, you can simply tac on the additional information that you would need at the bottom of the you list.  That is after you decide how to deal with a double log out or double log in.  Also how do you want to deal with multiple log ins.  user1 is log in via laptop, desktop, tablet and smart phone all from 08:00 to 09:00.  Is that a 4 hour long session or a 1 hour long session.